# How to deal with search queries which have spaces in the wrong place while making a search engine of an e-commerce website?

Tags: java, search, nlp, search-engine, tf-idf

Suppose I have an entry pepe jeans in the website. The user searches pepejeans. I am currently using tf-idf and cosine similarity for returning the most significant results, but I have kept the memory usage as small as possible because the content is large. So what can I use to deal with this problem? One solution is to keep the record with space and without space of all ngrams of the content.

Another example-
If the user searches for nikeshoes. Now nike is a brand but nikeshoes is not a brand. It the search query was nike shoes then it would have returned nike as brand.
The content here refers to brand names. I am trying to identify the brand name from the query

Comment: http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/the-word-break-problem/

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is to do a query rewrite before executing the query. During the query rewrite you can transform the query the user gave into a form that works better for your retrieval system. This can involve tokenization, stemming, spell check and other types of rewrites.

For an overview, see this blog post https://hughewilliams.com/2012/03/19/query-rewriting-in-search-engines/